# What is best way to overcome <knowledge:articleList> max number of calls exceeded: 4

Tags: visualforce, knowledge

The Knowledge object I am working with has 5 Article Types and I want to create a Community VF page that will show the 2-3 most recently published articles for each article type. I am not able to use the VF standard component " knowledge:articleList " because it has a max number of calls per page of 4. Is there a way I can work around that limit?  Is this a soft limit that support may possibly increase if asked?

Comment: i assume that putting a "see more" link at the bottom of the page that takes you to article types 5-8 was considered?

Comment: Not really only because for this project I wanted all of them on the same page.  What I did to get around the limitation is I used the component for 4 of the article types and then developed a quick custom controller to get the 5th one.

Comment: that works -- you should post your options and ultimate solution as an 'answer' here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used to solve this problem was to use the knowledge:articleList VF Component for the first 4 Article Types and then I used this custom Controller for the 5th one and any future ones if needed on this page

```
public with sharing class ShowArticleType {

private final KnowledgeArticleVersion[] articles;  

public ShowArticleType() {

}
    {
        articles = [SELECT Id, UrlName, Title, Summary, LastPublishedDate, ArticleType 
                    FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion 
                    WHERE PublishStatus= 'Online' 
                    AND Language = 'en_US' 
                    AND ArticleType = 'User_Guides__kav'
                    ORDER by LastPublishedDate DESC
                    LIMIT 4];
    }

    public KnowledgeArticleVersion[] getArticles() {
        return articles;
    }
}
```